# Chart database data connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, highcharts

I have problem with connecting my mysql database to Highstock chart
Here is my code - it does not show anything when I run it shows just empty page

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or send me example for the script with database connection?
I would really appreciate

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">


<?php    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost:3307","sampleuser","samplepass","sampledatabase");
if(!$conn)
{
 die("connection in error:".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$result=mysqli_query($conn,"Select time,open,close,high,low,volume From sampletable ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   extract $row;
   $time *= 1000; // convert from Unix timestamp to JavaScript time
   $data[] = "[$time,$open,$close,$high,$low,$volume]";
}
?>

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {


        title: {
            text: 'AAPL stock price by minute'
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                type: 'hour',
                count: 1,
                text: '1h'
            }, {
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '1D'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                count: 1,
                text: 'All'
            }],
            selected: 1,
            inputEnabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'AAPL',
            type: 'candlestick',
            data: data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });



  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The javascript variable ```data``` is not the same as the PHP variable ```data```.

Comment: how to fix it? @paski

Comment: echo the variable data to Javascript space. Create a js variable, and use PHP to output the data. If the data is too long you can ```json_encode``` it first and then decode it later in Javascript space.